# Is there a way to see the entire process of calculating the width and height of an element in HTML?

Tags: html, css, debugging

In the F12 developer tools you can see the calculated height and width.  Sometimes you can figure out what it was inherited from if the width or height was not set to an absolute number.  At other times you get the width and/or height without any indication of how it was calculated.

Is there some way to find out the entire calculation that went into any width or height?

It is difficult to determine what to change in CSS when it isn't clear want was driving the calculation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this isn't a code issue, dear bot